# Modelling states and sub-states using enums in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, state-machine, states

I have an object which has a state. This can be:

```
'scheduled', 'on-shift' or 'past'
```

In addition, 'on-shift' can be of state:

```
'available', 'busy' or 'inactive'
```

What is the best way to  model these states in my rails app?

Is it to:

a. create two state attributes:

```
 1. object_state - can take the value: 'scheduled', 'on-shift' or 'past'
 2. on_shift_state - can take the value: 'available', 'busy' or 'inactive'
```

b. create a single state attribute, which can take the value:

```
 'scheduled', 'past', 'available', 'busy' or 'inactive'.
```

c. some other way.

I think option b would ensure logical consistency in the database, but increase the complexity of queries, e.g. if I want to search for units which are  'on-shift', I need to search for 3 different states. It may also be harder to extend, e.g. if I want to add more states at a later date.

If I were to go with option b, is there some way to simplify the queries?

Any specific structures/methods you would suggest using?

note: I am thinking of using enums to model the state(s).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [State Machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) and storing your states in a single attribute.

With State Machine you just need to add a state field to your model and then you can define your states using the gem's DSL. State Machine will handle the logic of transitioning between states and will provide nice getters and setters for each state.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard good things about the state machine gem, although I thought it might be too heavy for my application. Any specific ideas on how to solve my issue using the gem? I understand how to define states, events and transitions, but not how to create sub-states, or groups of states.